# Spring Boot session when tab or browser closes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that incorporates Spring session management. However, I noticed that when I close a tab and try to go back into the site I get prompted with an error. Also, when I close out the browser, it makes me sign in again and I will see two sessions with the same principal id in my JDBC. So I am confused if I messed up some code in my security config or if this is typical behavior. Also, I relaze too that I need to find a way to immediately go back to login page if the user timeout is reached. Currently, if the user timeout is reached then there is no indication. I am new to Spring Boot session management and I have read some documentation online but some of the docs I have read are confusing. Any help would be appricaited.

**Security Config:**

```
    @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
          .authorizeRequests()        
          .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
           .and()
          .formLogin()
          .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())                 // On authentication success custom handler 
          .and()
          .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");



        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(50).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);

    }
```

**Application Properties:**

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=10m
```

Answer (score 1):

For the closing of browser and requiring you to sign in again:

If you have a network inspection tool, you'll notice that upon login there is a response header - `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=...` (assuming Tomcat).

This cookie is the ID that is associated with the session in your service and will be stored within the browser's cookie store. Subsequent requests on the same domain will send this cookie as a request header automatically. This is more-or-less how you can get the experience of signing in and then being able to interact with your secured pages/APIs without having to explicitly add anything.

If the cookie does not define an expiration, the browser will treat this cookie as a session cookie, which is transient or will only live until the browser is closed.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

The `server.servlet.session.timeout=10m` defines the session's time to live (TTL) on the server side. Assuming the user sends a session ID in the request, we still need to check if this session is valid/authenticated. One way of doing so could be that we just check if the session still exists in memory in Tomcat. In which case, with the timeout above, the session could have been evicted already.

In regards to the error upon closing the tab and trying again - if you can describe the error and/or post the stacktrace, that would help us in providing a diagnosis.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying back to my question, however there is no stacktrace or error. I really just wanted to be directed in a way in which I could accomplish have the user automatically go back to the login page if the session or in this case the cookie expired.

Comment: If you want to have users automatically redirected back to the login page, the client (or browser) is going to have be notified in some fashion. Assuming the session has timed out, you can either 1. kick the user out upon their next request and have that 302 redirect to login, 2. run a polling request that checks session state and upon expiration, have the client route to some link provided or 3. do some server-side push event.

Comment: The invalid session URL in spring session management might be able to help you out - [Spring Security - Detecting Timeouts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#detecting-timeouts) or [SessionManagementConfigurer Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/SessionManagementConfigurer.html)